# How to sort multiple columns of text up till a delimiter in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, text, split, multiple-columns

So I have a file that contains txt values like the following:

```
./run_1920x1080_2000_8_medium.txt encoded 279 frames, 44.63 fps, 1835.78 kb/s
./run_1920x1080_6000_8_medium.txt encoded 279 frames, 29.36 fps, 5504.96 kb/s
./run_1920x1080_2000_8_fast.txt encoded 279 frames, 46.96 fps, 1851.13 kb/s
./run_1920x1080_4000_4_faster.txt encoded 279 frames, 32.74 fps, 3631.55 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_4000_6_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 79.48 fps, 4003.93 kb/s
./greenleaves_1920x1080_6000_2_faster.txt encoded 299 frames, 16.12 fps, 6406.48 kb/s
./greenleaves_1920x1080_2000_2_veryslow.txt encoded 299 frames, 2.47 fps, 2076.77 kb/s
./run_1920x1080_2000_6_slower.txt encoded 279 frames, 11.36 fps, 1822.16 kb/s
./greenleaves_1920x1080_2000_6_slower.txt encoded 299 frames, 11.38 fps, 2069.65 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_4000_8_faster.txt encoded 299 frames, 53.87 fps, 3970.18 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_6000_6_superfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 126.51 fps, 6068.11 kb/s
./greenleaves_1920x1080_2000_8_slow.txt encoded 299 frames, 17.96 fps, 2055.69 kb/s
./greenleaves_1920x1080_2000_10_superfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 137.57 fps, 2081.60 kb/s
./greenleaves_1920x1080_6000_10_ultrafast.txt encoded 299 frames, 286.71 fps, 6548.01 kb/s
./run_1920x1080_6000_4_medium.txt encoded 279 frames, 19.01 fps, 5452.17 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_2000_4_medium.txt encoded 299 frames, 28.57 fps, 1965.14 kb/s
./greenleaves_1920x1080_6000_10_veryslow.txt encoded 299 frames, 5.55 fps, 6551.35 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_2000_10_medium.txt encoded 299 frames, 37.78 fps, 1947.80 kb/s
./run_1920x1080_4000_2_faster.txt encoded 279 frames, 18.91 fps, 3637.35 kb/s
./run_1920x1080_6000_10_slower.txt encoded 279 frames, 9.22 fps, 5580.57 kb/s
./greenleaves_1920x1080_6000_4_slow.txt encoded 299 frames, 8.22 fps, 6387.91 kb/s
./greenleaves_1920x1080_2000_4_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 63.49 fps, 2090.72 kb/s
./run_1920x1080_6000_8_superfast.txt encoded 279 frames, 127.40 fps, 5464.33 kb/s
./run_1920x1080_4000_2_slow.txt encoded 279 frames, 7.72 fps, 3638.49 kb/s
./run_1920x1080_2000_6_slow.txt encoded 279 frames, 18.94 fps, 1832.48 kb/s
./run_1920x1080_6000_10_superfast.txt encoded 279 frames, 124.19 fps, 5477.19 kb/s
```

The goal is to sort the file in the following order:

1. column 1 (file name)
2. column 5 (preset)
3. column 4 (threads)
4. column 3 (bit rate)

What I did was the following:

```
sort -t_ -k1,1 -k5,5 -k4,4
```

I am able to generate:

```
./soccer_1920x1080_6000_10_ultrafast.txt encoded 299 frames, 289.95 fps, 6213.30 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_6000_8_ultrafast.txt encoded 299 frames, 297.17 fps, 6161.19 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_2000_6_ultrafast.txt encoded 299 frames, 309.66 fps, 2007.68 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_2000_8_ultrafast.txt encoded 299 frames, 313.22 fps, 2008.35 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_4000_6_ultrafast.txt encoded 299 frames, 326.60 fps, 4043.20 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_2000_10_ultrafast.txt encoded 299 frames, 328.80 fps, 2002.80 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_2000_2_ultrafast.txt encoded 299 frames, 53.80 fps, 1998.31 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_4000_2_ultrafast.txt encoded 299 frames, 80.76 fps, 4001.73 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_6000_2_ultrafast.txt encoded 299 frames, 94.61 fps, 6017.98 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_2000_2_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 29.26 fps, 1983.19 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_6000_2_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 30.87 fps, 6123.24 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_4000_2_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 42.24 fps, 4021.40 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_6000_4_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 56.77 fps, 6104.80 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_4000_4_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 58.16 fps, 4006.02 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_2000_4_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 59.07 fps, 1968.70 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_6000_8_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 72.76 fps, 6125.40 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_4000_8_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 75.88 fps, 3988.52 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_2000_8_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 78.52 fps, 1952.13 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_4000_6_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 79.48 fps, 4003.93 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_6000_6_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 81.29 fps, 6141.92 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_4000_10_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 82.81 fps, 3987.88 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_6000_10_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 83.13 fps, 6148.43 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_2000_10_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 84.36 fps, 1953.51 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_2000_6_veryfast.txt encoded 299 frames, 85.84 fps, 1966.70 kb/s
./soccer_1920x1080_6000_2_veryslow.txt encoded 299 frames, 2.11 fps, 6100.42 kb/s
```

I am unable to properly sort the 4th column because the 5th column is considered to be everything after the last "_". So how can I sort the input while ignoring everything in the 5th column after the ".txt"?

Comment: Why are you using `_` as field delimiter? If the reason for that is to sort 10 after 5, (number 10 > 5, but as a string 10 < 5), see if your `sort` has a `-V` option (version sort)

Comment: It's just what the code outputs, I kind of have no say in it.

Comment: I mean, why are you using `_` as delimiter in your sort command?

Comment: The input I have provided above is part of a larger output file generated by a different command. I cannot change it, thus using "_" as a delimiter.

Comment: OK, I interpreted that `./soccer_1920x1080_6000_2_veryslow.txt` entirely is file name & further fields are other columns...

Answer (score 0):

An imperfect solution is to define column 5 as a fixed-length field: `-k5,5.8`. That assumes that any two different values in that field will differ in the first eight characters, and that all values are at least seven characters long (including the space shouldn't change anything).

By the way, the numeric fields should have `n` modifiers -- `-k4,4n` -- so that `10` doesn't sort before `8`.

If there is no suitable value for the number `8` above, your only alternative is to take the lines apart before the sort and restore them afterwards. For example:

```
sed 's/ /_/' file |
sort -t_ -k1,1 -k5,5 -k4,4n -k3,3n |
sed 's/\(\([^_]*_)\{4\}[^_]*\)_/\1 /'
```

The first `sed` changes the first space of each line to an underscore, and the second one changes the fifth underscore back to a space.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!